# perfect-scrollbar plugin On reaching bottom, fires the event multiple times

Tags: javascript, dom-events, perfect-scrollbar

I am using perfect-scroll plugin

https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar

And when I used the `ps-y-reach-end` event

[image]

```
document.addEventListener('ps-y-reach-end', (event)=> {
   console.log('Why this is printing multiple times when I reach Bottom, I wanted it to be single fire')
 });
```

Problem is the event fires more than once, when the scroll reached to the bottom of the container.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xv0rrxv3/460/)

Web console prints : 
 [image]

Please scroll the y-axis to the bottom and you will see the consoles multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a boolean flag to handle this

```
var el = document.querySelector('.container');

Ps.initialize(el);
let loading = false
document.addEventListener('ps-y-reach-end', (event) => {
    if (!loading) {
        loading = true
        alert('Why this is printing multiple times when I reach Bottom, I wanted it to be single fire')
    }

});
```